# Difficulty in receiving POST parameter in symfony using angular 4

Tags: php, angular, symfony

I am using symfony with angular 4. Both are different projects. In symfony I am returning a post variable which is sent via angular. I am just returning the value. Nothing other than that.

But it's returning me blank value. But when I am testing that symfony url using postman it's returning the correct value.

**Symfony code**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,Accept');

return new Response("a-".$request->request->get('roll')."-b"); //gives  '**a- -b**' in console. but from postman gives `a-2-b`
```

**Angular code**

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/user/login",{roll:2}).subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
);
```

Comment: try this code to see if you get the data $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);dump($data);

Comment: totally blank in postman also

Comment: use your angular application

Comment: blank in both places

Comment: normally via post angular send the data as Content-Type: application/json and symfony expecte Content-Type est application/x-www-form-urlencoded that why you get the blank

Comment: You’ve checked the browser devtools console for error messages? If so you should use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45418401/edit to edit/update your question and add the exact error message you’re seeing.

Comment: I am not sure, but what we can say for sure is that something about the request is different. Maybe you can tell what the network tab in DeveloperExtensionWindow in the browser tells... if there is a failed request, maybe even a log about it, it could be that you need to allow the HTTP Method "Options" as well - this is a descriptive http request for angular - if this one fails the get request will never be sent - wow i am late sry :D

Answer (score 0):

Your postman's POST request is different than the Angular's POST request
Maybe in Angular you have to add the `content-type: application/json` header.

To debugging I advice you to compare the two request with logging in symfony code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe you have to JSON.stringify your object on the angular side:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/user/login",JSON.stringify({roll:2})).subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
);
```

Next, as said in comments above. Symfony handles x-www-form-urlencoded body by default. For JSON requests you will need to parse it yourself.

e.g.:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
```

Now doing this in every controller action may seem tedious and you'll loose the Symfony Parameter bag.

You can solve this by making a Request listener:

e.g.:

```
class JsonRequestEventListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (empty($request->getContent()))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!$this->isJsonRequest($request))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!$this->transformJsonBody($request))
        {
            $response = Response::create('Unable to parse request.', 400);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }

    private function isJsonRequest(Request $request)
    {
        return 'json' === $request->getContentType();
    }

    private function transformJsonBody(Request $request)
    {
        $content = $request->getContent();
        if ($content === '')
        {
            return true;
        }
        $data = json_decode($content, true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ($data === null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        $request->request->replace($data);

        return true;
    }
}
```

What this listener does is the following:

When a request comes in, it checks if there is any content and if the request is json. Then it tries to json_decode the request and inserts it in the request parameter bag. ($request->request ...)

The next thing you will have to do is register this listener:

e.g.:

```
jsonrequest.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\JsonRequestEventListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 100 }
```

And from now on, if your request is of type application/json and it contains valid json, you can find it's values in the Request Parameter bag:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->request->all() //holds the json
}
```

As I can see from your sample, you set the CORS headers in your controller as well. You could in the same way write a CORS listener to handle this for you.